# Weird characters only showing in ie

Tags: wordpress, character

I was just informed by my client that three weird characters are showing on certain sections of their site, but only in internet explorer. I'm not the original developer of the site as it was done before I started at my current job. The site is done in Wordpress and it is in both English and Russian. I've searched for a fix but am at a loss. The three characters are +*- and they are appearing before each attorney's title. You can see the problem at http://marks-sokolov.com/attorney-profiles/. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: its in the generated html. Chrome just hides it. if you view the source file in chrome, it is actually there, just chrome renders it as double quotes.  You will need to dig into the code to find out why its there. My guess is its a unsupported character in the encoding you are using.

Comment: Good catch. I actually hadn't noticed it was in the source on all browsers. It seems like it has something to do with the excerpt as the characters show on the blog where the excerpt is displayed as well. I just can't seem to find where the excerpt rules are defined. I checked the functions file but there is no mention of the excerpt in there. I'll have to keep digging I guess.